# SELECT n row FROM table1 PER table2

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 table: Cats(category) and post. 
I want to SELECT n post per each category.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM cat
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT * FROM post WHERE post.CatID=cat.ID LIMIT 3 ) ...
```

The problem is MySQL does not recognize cat.ID inside sub query.

Regards

Comment: I must mention that i don't want to `LIMIT` output to **n**. I want to retrieve n Row **per each category**. For example if u have 5 category, with `LIMIT 3`, your result must be 15 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID, 
        a.Category,
        b.Description
FROM    Category a
        INNER JOIN Post b
            ON a.ID = b.Cat_ID
WHERE   
(
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM    Post c
    WHERE   b.Cat_ID = c.Cat_ID AND
            b.ID <= c.ID
) <= 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2265/4)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. Thanks for SQLFiddle too.